# Setting a value in a column within a group according to some condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm new to groups in pandas, and relatively new to pandas, so I hope someone of you can help me with my problem.

Aim:  flag outliers within a group by setting the relevant cell in the relevant column to 1.The condition is that the data point is outside a calculated group specific limit.

Data: This is a geopandas dataframe with multiple time series with some numeric variables. Each timeseries has its own id.

Some background:
I want to determine outliers for each timeseries by

1. first grouping the timeseries according to timeseries id
2. then calculate the lower and upper limit of the variables PER group
3. then 'flag' the values which are outside the limit by adding a 1 in a specific 'outlier'column

Here is the code which calculates the limits, however, when it comes to setting the flag I have a hard time to figure that out:

```
df_timeseries['outlier'] = np.zeros
for timeseries, group in df_timeseries.groupby('timeseries.id'):
    Q1 = group['Variable.value'].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = group['Variable.value'].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    low_lim = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
    up_lim = Q3 + 1.5 *IQR
    for value in group['Variable.value']:
        if ((value < low_lim) or (value > up_lim)):
      #      here --> set '1' in the column 'outlier'
```

I tried it multiple ways, for example:

```
df_timeseries.loc[df_timeseries['Variable.value'] > up_lim, 'outlier']=1
```

I also tried 'apply()', so instead of iterating over the tracks I tried to first define a function and then apply it on the group. However nothing really worked, and I could not find out what I actually do wrong. If someone can help, I would be really glad, as I have already tried to figure this out about a couple of hours.

I would need something like:

```
group.loc[group['outlier']] = 1
```